# c# XML \r \n error

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have code for read `xml:`

```
string xmlread = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
Custom custom = new Custom();
TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(xmlread));
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(custom));
custom = (Custom)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);
```

but `xml` has the form

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<instacheat>\n  <hash>5d02c2151c9d147b2219b371b7d383b3665e</hash>\n</instacheat>\n\r\n
```

and because gives me an error "It contains invalid characters."

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Side note: I believe it should be `typeof(Custom)`

Comment: `(Custom)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream());`

Comment: It's *completely* unclear what you mean by “XML \r \n error”. **And don't repeat tags in question titles.**

Comment: I guess what you see is in debugger window. just click the magnifier icon when you view the xml in debugger.

Comment: FYI, it makes no sense to use `Custom custom = new Custom();` and then set `custom` to the return of the `Deserialize` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the stream reader to detect the text encoding:

```
string xmlread = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of \r\n, I suggest using a regex as a quick solution

```
xmlread = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(xmlread, @"\\r|\\n", "")
```